# how to add a value in a numpy array enclosed in two square brackets

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have got some numbers in my "two column and bidimensional" dataframe and next necessarily converted into a simple numpy array:

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1')
df = np.array(df)
dfx= df[:, np.newaxis, 0]
dfy= df[:, np.newaxis, 1]
print(dfx)

[[1069205.1]
 [ 950438.8]
 [ 838167.5]
 [ 746126.5]
 [ 811380]]
```

I would like to add into dfx one number more but if I write:

```
dfx=np.append(dfx, [3000000])
```

I get something which looks like a list:

```
(1069205.1, 950438.83, 838167.5, 746126.5, 811380.0, 3000000.0)
```

while I'd like to get the same previous type enclosed in between two square brackets as I figures it out below:

```
[[1069205.1]
 [ 950438.8]
 [ 838167.5]
 [ 746126.5]
 [ 811380]
 [ 3000000]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`np.vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
dfx = np.vstack((dfx, [3000000]))
```

Comment: Thanks @mck the correct syntax that is working fine is  dfx= np.vstack((dfx, 3500000))